# как выделить цветом конкретный пункт в autocomplete mui

Tags: reactjs, mui

у меня есть такой селект

```
<Autocomplete
  id="instruments"
  options={allInstruments}
  value={instrument}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => handleInstruments(newValue)}
  defaultValue={allInstruments[0]}
  size="small"
  sx={{ mt: 0.2, flexGrow: 2 }}
  getOptionLabel={tool => tool.title}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Инструменты" />}
/>
```

я хочу чтобы конкретный items в это поле были выделены цветом, например если tool.title = 'asd' то style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
кто-нибудь может подсказать как это делается и делается ли вообще?